# JQuery, cloning a div more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt2czgse/50/) set up.  At the moment, I have three divs, each with their own input.  Each input has a checkbox where another input can be added.  If unchecked the input is then removed again.  The code for this is

```
 $(function() {
   $('input:checkbox[name="labelNewline"]').change(function() {
     if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
       var clone = $(this).parent().siblings(".labelAndInput").first().clone().insertAfter($(this).parent());
       clone.addClass('clone');
     } else {
            $(this).parent().siblings(".clone").remove();
     }
   });
 });
```

I am trying now to do something else.  If a new line is added, the new input should also get a checkbox with the ability to add a new input.  So I no longer want to limit this to only one input being added.  However, if the checkbox for an input is unchecked, it should remove its related input.

Would something like this be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Here's a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yvnyk69v/1/

Things of note:

```
$("#testingContainer").delegate('input:checkbox[name="labelNewline"]', 'change', function() {
```

The delegate function is really useful in this case.  What it does it it takes an element, and will apply an event handler to any element that matches the selector specified in the delegate function, even if it's added after code has already run.

The UI was pretty simple, so I was able to target elements with next and previous.  If it becomes more complex, you may want to add a an attribute or class to more easily identify the corresponding inputs.